# How would you change this kind of code?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, but I'm still pretty new to jQuery and I'm pretty sure this is messy code that can be made shorter or maybe use less variables to create a better dynamic plugin. I'm trying to experiment with different types of logic. Here's the code.

```
$.pluginName = (function () {
    $(function () {
        var message = "Hello World!";
        var animSpeed = 300;
        var animType = 'fadeIn';
        var icon = "pin";
        var btnText = "Purchase";
        var btnColor = "pink";
        var btnLink = 'http://www.google.com';
        var content = '<div id="mn_close" class="light"></div>' + '<div id="mn_border"></div>' + '<i class="icon-' + icon + '"></i>' + '<span class="mn_message">' + message + '</span>' + '<a href="' + btnLink + '" class="button ' + btnColor + '">' + btnText + '</a>';
        $("#mn_close").live("click", function () {
            $('.mn_bar').animate({
                top: '-50'
            }, animSpeed, function () {});
        });
        $(".mn_bar").append(content);
        $(function () {
            $(".mn_bar").addClass("animated");
            $(".mn_bar").addClass(animType);
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Any tips on how to pass these variables in to options that the user can change dynamically from a HTML source? I'm not expecting detailed answers, but I'd appreciate any help passed on.

EDI: JS Fiddle with CSS & HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/QjFnf/8/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here it is on jsfiddle, although the HTML is still missing: http://jsfiddle.net/QjFnf/

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not sure what version of jQuery you're using, but since 1.7 `live` is deprecated, you should replace it with `on` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: if all the vars is an 'option', I'd prefer to put it in an option object: `var option = { message : "Hello World!" , "animSpeed : 300, ... };` this way, if in the future you want to pass around options, you just need to pass the option variable instead of each variable one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Great community as always! I've added an updated JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QjFnf/8/

Comment: Please edit your question title to something that has information about your question, and that is useful in a search for future users. "How would you change this kind of code" is meaningless in a search, and it conveys nothing useful when viewing your question on the main page of this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
(function( $ ){

  var _defaults = {
    message = 'Hello World!',
    animSpeed = 300,
    animType = 'fadeIn',
    icon = 'pin',
    btnText = 'Purchase',
    btnColor = 'pink',
    btnLink = 'http://www.google.com'
  };

  $.pluginName = function( opts ) {

    var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, opts )
      , $bar = $('.mn_bar').addClass('animated '+ animType)
      , $close = $('<div id="mn_close" class="light"/>')
      , $icon = $('<i class="icon-"'+ o.icon +'></i>')
      , $message = $('<span class="mn_message">'+ o.message +'</span>')
      , $link = $('<a href="'+ o.btnLink +'" class="button "'+ o.btnColor +'>'+ o.btnText +'</a>');

    $close.click(function(){
      $bar.animate({ top: '-50px' }, animSpeed );
    });

    $bar.append( $bar, $close, $icon, $message, $link );

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @kennypu comment, I've done this:
I haven't tested it at all, but I think this is a good way to refactor your plugin :

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {

        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend( {
            message : "Hello World!",
            animSpeed : 300,
            animType : 'fadeIn',
            icon : "pin",
            btnText : "Purchase",
            btnColor : "pink",
            btnLink : 'www.google.com',
        }, options);

        // A tidier way to create the content would be to use jQuery like this : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2
        var content : '<div id="mn_close" class="light"></div>' + '<div id="mn_border"></div>' + '<i class="icon-' + settings.icon + '"></i>' + '<span class="mn_message">' + settings.message + '</span>' + '<a href="' + settings.btnLink + '" class="button ' + settings.btnColor + '">' + settings.btnText + '</a>';

        var mn_bar = $(".mn_bar");
        mn_bar.append(content);

         $("#mn_close").on("click", function () {
            mn_bar.animate({
                top: '-50'
            }, settings.animSpeed, function () {});
        });


        mn_bar.addClass("animated " + settings.animType);

    })
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT : I set a variable for `.mn_bar` because there is no reason to look for this element in the DOM again. And I also removed the two calls to `addClass()` and made only one.

Comment: be careful using global variables in plugin `content` should be `var content` so it isn't global