# How to turn variables in to options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you change this kind of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048723/how-would-you-change-this-kind-of-code)

How would I pass these variables in to options through jQuery, so that when the user uses the plugin, they must initialize the plugin from the HTML like so:

```
 <script>
    $('.elem').pluginName({
       theme: 'blue',
       animSpeed: 200
    });
 </script>
```

Here's my jQuery code. Pretty messy, but have a look. How could I change the variables to options?

```
$(function () {

    var theme = "sunburst";
    var btnColor = "yellow";
    var icon = "power";
    var message = "Hello World";
    var animSpeed = 300;
    var animType = 'fadeIn';
    var btnText = "Purchase";
    var btnLink = 'http://www.google.com';
    var closeStyle = "dark";

    var content =
        '<div id="mn_close" class="' + closeStyle + '"></div>' +
        '<div id="mn_border"></div>' +
        '<i class="icon-' + icon + '"></i>' +
        '<span class="mn_message">' + message + '</span>';
        //  '<a href="' + btnLink + '" class="button ' + btnColor + '">' + btnText + '</a>';


    $("#mn_close").live("click", function () {
        $('.mn_bar').animate({
            height: '0'
        }, animSpeed, function () {});
    });
    var mn_bar = $(".mn_bar");
    mn_bar.append(content);
    $(function () {
        mn_bar.addClass("animated");
        mn_bar.addClass(animType);
        mn_bar.addClass(theme)
    });
});
```

Or here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LwGRV/6/

I've being trying to implement the code in to this standard type of jQuery code too, but failing to merge:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
        },

        yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
            // some logic
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Many thanks in advance if anyone can shed some light on to this.

Comment: It is, the problem is that was closed for an unrelated question/off topic, except I made it relevant this time, with a different query. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the two answers you got showing you how to convert from variables to options?

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery documentation on  "Plugin authoring". Unless your plugin is eventually getting bigger, you don't need the jQuery Plugin Boilerplate.

Comment: Plus I answered [this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048723/how-would-you-change-this-kind-of-code) already. Analyze the code see and why it works. I showed you how to use `$.extend` to create default options.

Comment: @elclanrs - thanks. Just reading it through it now properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/
Your variables should be stored within an object.